# Need to fill Gridview checkbox attribute from a cell data or database data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

Hi guys,

I am not a developer but I always try my best to manage my page coding by myself before bothering anyone and by checking many examples and apply them to my web application, but this time I really surrendered and had to ask.

I have a Gridview where I will be using to update one field which is CHECKBOX.
The gridview has a checkbox control where it's checked attribute need to be True or False based on the Database value.
Values are 1 and 2 only

I wrote the below code to catch the cell label and change the checkbox attribute but it didn't work

```
Protected Sub Refill_checkbox(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To dg.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim Test As String = CType(dg.Rows(i).Cells(3).FindControl("Att_Type"), Label).Text

        If CType(dg.Rows(i).Cells(4).FindControl("Att_Type"), Label).Text = 1 Then

            CType(dg.Rows(i).Cells(6).FindControl("CheckBox_Attendance"), CheckBox).Checked = True
        Else
            CType(dg.Rows(i).Cells(6).FindControl("CheckBox_Attendance"), CheckBox).Checked = False
        End If
        Response.Write(Test)
    Next

End Sub
```

Unfortunately it even did not write the Test Variable to find if it catches the label from the gridview or not.

My Gridview is as following:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="dg" runat="server" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
                      BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
                      EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" 
                      Width="99%"  AllowPaging="True" PageSize="500" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BCS" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                 <ItemTemplate>  
                        <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Att_ID" HeaderText="Att_ID" 
                    SortExpression="Att_ID" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_FullName" HeaderText="Emp_FullName" 
                    SortExpression="Emp_FullName" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Att_Desc" HeaderText="Att_Desc" 
                    SortExpression="Att_Desc" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Att_Type" HeaderText="Att_Type" 
                    SortExpression="Att_Type" />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Att_Date" HeaderText="Att_Date" 
                    SortExpression="Att_Date" />


    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Attendance" >

        <itemtemplate  >

         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_Attendance" runat="server"  />

        </itemtemplate>
        <itemstyle horizontalalign="left" />

    </asp:templatefield> 

                            </Columns>

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" BorderWidth="0px"/>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have no idea what is the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your checkbox directly to the field like so...

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_Attendance" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Att_type").ToString() = "1" %>'  />
```

---

Otherwise, handle it directly on your gridview rowdatabound event:

**Put the following on your gridview:**

```
<asp:GridView ... OnRowDatabound="dg_RowDataBound">
```

**Change your TemplateField to look like this:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attendance">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField id="hfType" Value='<%# Eval("Att_Type") %>' />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_Attendance" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**In your code behind**

```
Protected Sub dg_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
      Dim cbAttendance As Checkbox = e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox_Attendance")
      Dim hfType as Hiddenfield = e.Row.FindControl("hfType")

      If hfType.Value = "1" Then
         cbAttendance.Checked = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was traying for hours :(